# Python - How to only select certain range of numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

This array, to what we can call `M_vir1`, has a ton of values with a shape of `(7713601,)`

```
[  2.32309127e+14   2.22871759e+14   2.17820810e+14 ...,   1.06466488e+08
   1.94144768e+08   0.00000000e+00]
```

I'm wanting to plot only values from the range `8e+11 - 2.4e+14`

How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolean arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to select the ones that satisfy the condition:

```
M_vir1[(8e+11 < M_vir1) & (M_vir1 < 2.4e+14)]
Out[111]: array([  2.32309127e+14,   2.22871759e+14,   2.17820810e+14])
```